# How do I solve this exponential function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following exponential equation:
$3\sqrt 5\cdot 2^n=(1+\sqrt 5)^n-(1-\sqrt 5)^n$. How do I solve it?

P.S. I can already see $n=4$, but I am interested in how to solve this using logarithms.

Comment: The addition makes it not so straight forward to use logarithms to solve this. I don't even know how to solve equations of the form $a^n+b^n=c$ in general.

Comment: It may help to note that $$a^n=e^{n\ln a}$$ so then you could at least get everything in the same base...

Comment: @clathratus thanks I will try that now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
3\sqrt5\,2^n&=(1+\sqrt 5)^n-(1-\sqrt 5)^n
\tag{1}\label{1}
\end{align}

Let's denote $1+\sqrt 5=a$, $\sqrt 5-1=b,\ b>0$.

Note that
\begin{align}
a\cdot b&=4=2^2
.
\end{align}

Consider $n=2m$, $m\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Then \eqref{1} transforms into
\begin{align}
3\sqrt5\,2^{2m}&=a^{2m}-(-b)^{2m}
\tag{2}\label{2}
,\\
3\sqrt5\,(2^2)^m&=a^{2m}-((-b)^2)^m
,\\
3\sqrt5\,(ab)^m&=a^{2m}-(b^{2m})
,\\
3\sqrt5\,\left(\frac{a}b\right)^m
&=\left(\frac{a}b\right)^{2m}
-1
.
\end{align}

Let $(\tfrac{a}b)^m=x$,

\begin{align}
x^2-3\sqrt5 x-1&=0
,\\
x&=\tfrac72+\tfrac32\sqrt5 \quad\text{(ignore negative root)}
,\\
(\tfrac{a}b)^m&=\tfrac72+\tfrac32\sqrt5
,\\
m&=
\frac{\ln(\tfrac72+\tfrac32\sqrt5
)}{\ln(\tfrac32+\tfrac12\sqrt5)}
\\
&=
\frac{\ln((\tfrac32+\tfrac12\sqrt5)^2)}{\ln(\tfrac32+\tfrac12\sqrt5)}
\\
&=
\frac{2\ln(\tfrac32+\tfrac12\sqrt5)}{\phantom{2}\ln(\tfrac32+\tfrac12\sqrt5)}
=2
,\\
n&=2m=4
.
\end{align}

Comment: Ok, this is what I was looking for, but shouldn't the case $n=2m+1$ also be covered?

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself, follow similar steps and you will see that $m \notin \mathbb{Z}$ therefore discarding this case.

Comment: @DarkAtom: yes, you should check this case too.

Answer (score 1):

This equation is just $\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\phi^n-\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\psi^n=F_n=3$, where $F_n$ denotes the $n$th Fibonacci number, so the answer is $n=4$.

See [Binet's Formula](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Binet%27s_Formula)

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

Observe that

$$\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}=\frac{-2}{1+\sqrt{5}}$$